# ironpython instantiate C++ class in python

Tags: c++, ironpython

I'm trying to instantiate a class written in C++ from python. For some reason, I'm getting a syntax error when invoking the "print" method, which takes no argument and should just print an int:

```
IronPython 2.7.5b2 (2.7.5.0) on .NET 4.0.30319.18444 (32-bit)
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import clr
>>> clr.AddReferenceToFileAndPath('c:\\users\\pletzer\\documents\\visual studio
>>> \\Projects\\AlexTest\\Debug\\AlexTest.dll')
>>> import at
>>> a = at.AlexTest(2)
>>> a.print()
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    a.print()
  ^
```

SyntaxError: syntax error

Thanks in advance for any suggestion. The C++ class is

```
// AlexTest.h

#include <iostream>
#pragma once

using namespace System;

namespace at {

    public ref class AlexTest
    {
    public:
        AlexTest(int i) {
            mi = i;
        }
        void print() {
            std::cout << "mi = i\n";
        }
    private:
        int mi;
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing the name of the method from "print" to "display" fixes the issue.

Also, can use (raw string r'...')

clr.AddReferenceToFileAndPath(r'c:\users\pletzer\documents\visual studio\Projects\AlexTest\Debug\AlexTest.dll')

to avoid having to type double back slashes

Comment: The reason is that `print` is a keyword in (Iron)Python 2 and thus can't be used as a member name.